# py-spy: how to run scripts with dependencies?

Tags: python, profiling

running the following on windows 10

```
C:\code\EPMD\Kodex-1.4.6\EPD_Prerequisite\Anaconda2\Scripts/py-spy.exe --nonblocking -- python C:\code\EPMD\Kodex-1.4.6\Applications\EPMD-Software\Preprocessor/Main.py
```

gives

> import error, no module named <>

even though the script Main.py is running fine.

How do I make [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) recognize imports?

Answer (score 0):

This should just work. Can you create an issue on github?

As a work around, you can run the program yourself and get py-spy to profile it by passing the PID.